# Black Scholes derivation and Ito's Product

Tags: black-scholes

In this derivation of the Black Scholes equation can someone please explain the last step where the author uses Ito's product rule? I do not understand where the "rC" term comes from.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, [Itô's product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma#Product_rule_for_It%C3%B4_processes) is $$\text d(XY)=X\text dY+Y\text dX+\text dX\text dY.$$

In your example, we have $X=\frac1B$ and $Y=C$ such that
$$\text d\left(\frac{C}B\right) = \frac1B\text dC+C\text d\left(\frac1B\right) + \text d\left(\frac1B\right)\text dC.$$

Because $\text dB= rB\text dt$ and $\text d(1/x) = -1/x^2\text dx$, we have $\text d\left(\frac1B\right)=-\frac1{B^2} \text dB=-\frac{r}B\text dt$. Thus, $$\text d\left(\frac{C}B\right) = \frac1B\text dC-\frac{rC}{B}\text{d}t.$$

As is standard, $$\text{d}C = \left(C_t+rSC_S+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2C_{SS}\right)\text{d}t+\sigma SC_S\text{d}W.$$

Putting everything together gives the desired result, namely $$\text{d}C = \frac{1}{B}\left(C_t+rSC_S+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2C_{SS}-rC\right)\text{d}t+\sigma \frac{S}{B}C_S\text{d}W.$$